# How to remove the words 'Who?' and 'When?' in the title page of Bergen beamer theme?

Tags: beamer, author, date, section-titles

I am creating a simple presentation using the `Bergen` theme in `beamer`. I like almost everything about it, except the words 'Who?' and 'When' as respective quantifiers for the `author` and `date` in the `titlepage`. How do I remove them?

The above being my first and foremost question, I have another request to the kind-hearted persons out here. Is it possible in a simple manner to embed the `section` headings in the `sidebar` in this theme, and to highlight the appropriate one while presenting? Much like the behaviour in the `Berkeley` theme?

The second one is only an added request. I really need to remove those two words from the `titlepage`. Please help. Following is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Bergen}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\author[]{Subhajit Paul}
\title{Report of Even Semester, 2020-21}
\subtitle{Salesian College, Siliguri Campus}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove 'Who' and 'When', add the following in the preamble

```
\def\insertauthorindicator{}% Default is "Who?"
\def\insertdateindicator{}% Default is "When?"
```

For the second part, add the following to the preamble

```
\useoutertheme[left]{sidebar}
```

Comment: Thank you. Any comment on the add on request?

Comment: @SubhajitPaul Updated the answer.